# If A is regular, then $AA^T$ is positive definite, since $x^TAA^Tx=(A^Tx)^T(A^Tx)>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I read this statement and didn't understand why the right part of the equation is true.

Namely, that: $(A^Tx)^T(A^Tx)>0$

Can someone explain? Thank you.

Comment: It's of the form $y^Ty$ where all entries are real. Compute this product explicitly.

Comment: @GitGud Could we extend this to say that even if A is not regular, then AA^T is positive semi-definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any vector $\;x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in\Bbb R^n\;$ , we get

$$x^tx=(x_1,...,x_n)\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\...\\x_n\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{k=1}^mx_i^2$$

If for some $\;1\le i\le n\;$ we have $\;x_i\neq0\;$ then ...

Comment: Could we extend this to say that even if A is not regular, then AA^T is positive semi-definite?

Comment: Yes @alan213123, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
(AB)^T=B^TA^T,
$$
we have that
$$
(A^Tx)^T=x^T(A^T)^T=x^TA.
$$